# FATAL ERROR - white page - no site showing

Tags: cache, fatal-error, options

This is the message that I got shortly after I clicked on the option to upgrade to the newest version of Wordpress. I made the mistake of NOT backing up my files somewhere and now I am wondering if I have to rebuild the site from scratch. I do not have direct access to the host server. What do you advise?

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /home/andrewb/public_html/DanielaSzasz11.com/wp-includes/option.php on line 1117

Answer (score 0):

Were you using any cache plugins like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)?

If so, you'll need to get access via sftp or ssh to disable the plugin (rename the dir `wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache` to something else).

Comment: It is possible. As I have no access to any of the "backend" side of the site, I can not see the plug ins.What is sftp (is this only accessed thru the cpanel?) By the way thanks for your help.

Comment: sftp stands for secure file transfer protocol. It's how you would access the files of your site. You could also access them via cPanel which is easiest for non-technical people. :-) Contacting your host company is probably the easiest solution. Also, make sure to vote up the answers that helped you so we get credit for our contributions. :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like the upgrade failed at some point. you will have to contact your hosting to help you redo the upgrade

Comment: Thanks. I already have. Will let you know how it works out so others can learn from my mistakes...lol